# Find eigenvalues of a Hermitian $2\times 2$-matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider the complex vector space $\mathbb C^2$ with the standard complex inner product. Let
>   $$
> A=\begin{bmatrix}2&i\\-i&2\end{bmatrix}.
> $$
>   Find $U$ such that $U^*AU=\Lambda$ is a real diagonal matrix.

I started of with calculating $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, which yielded to
$$
\lambda^2-2\lambda+3=0.
$$
So we get $\lambda=1\pm i\sqrt 2$

Let's calculate the $(1+i\sqrt2)$-eigenspace:
$\begin{aligned}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1-i\sqrt 2&i&0\\
-i&1-i\sqrt 2&0
\end{array}
\right]&\iff
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&i/(1-i\sqrt 2)&0\\
0&1-i\sqrt 2+1/(1-i\sqrt 2)&0
\end{array}\right]\\
&\iff
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&i/(1-i\sqrt 2)&0\\
0&(-2i\sqrt 2)/(1-i\sqrt 2)&0
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$

And here I get a rank 2 matrix, it seems. Did I make a mistake somewhere in my calculations? I can't figure out what it could have been.

I'm guessing something went wrong when I divided by a complex number. I am going to multiply the first row by $(1+i\sqrt 2)$, which will yield in an upper left entry of value 3. And then I'll divide by 3.

*edit*; Actually, that approach also yields to a non-zero last row; $\begin{bmatrix}0&2/3-2/3i\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$. So the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with dividing by a complex number.

Comment: To know easier what rank you have it can help to multiply with denominator conjugate everywhere to make sure get real number in denominators. For example: $i/(1-i\sqrt 2) = i(1+i\sqrt 2)/3$

Comment: @mathreadler yea, I did that, but that still leaves me with an apparent rank 2 matrix (see edit)

Comment: $A $ is hermitian,  Hence the eigenvalues are real! Your char. polynomial is false

Comment: I get $(2-\lambda)^2-i\cdot(-i) = (2-\lambda)^2-1 = /\text{ conjugate rule }/ =  (2-\lambda-1)(2-\lambda+1))$

Comment: Thanks @Fred! I completely forgot that the eigenvalues should be real. I get the same polynomial as mathreadler now.